# Server document root variable is empty (Apache MAMP)

Tags: php, macos, apache, mamp

I'm having a problem with proper configuration of my MAMP apache server. Problem is following: variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is always empty.

In my httpd.conf i have configured

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/<user>/workspace"
<Directory "/Users/<user>/workspace">    
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    XSendFilePath "/Users/<user>/workspace"
</Directory>
```

This is my vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myApp.dev
    ServerAlias *.myApp.dev
    ServerAdmin info@myApp.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp"
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp/rest/application/logs/myApp.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp/rest/application/logs/myApp.dev-access_log" common
    <Directory   "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

And when i var_dump variable

```
var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
die();
```

result is

```
string(0) ""
```

What else do i need to do in order to get document root value printed out? If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Did you do the commande « sudo a2ensite httpd.conf » To enable the conf ?

Comment: do you really need to do that? I'm using MAMP on macOS

Comment: Did you restart Apache begin by that sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: yes i have restarted whole Mamp stack after changing configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I was running php trough terminal! If you `print_r($_SERVER)` you will see that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not set!

If I print `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in browser i see proper path as it should be